# Rate limiting based on multiple keys for same route

Tags: rate-limiting, spring-cloud-gateway

We are using spring-cloud-gateway for rate limiting using RedisRateLimiter. Everything works right out of box if we have one key to rate limit by per route. However, we have a use case where for a single given route. we want to do rate limiting by multiple tiers. For example, for a given route id 1, we want to rate limit a certain user in a pool by 10 requests per second. However, at the same time we also want to rate limit overall pool requests to 100 per second for same route. So basically using 2 different keys for same route while keeping track of each at same time.

We tried using rate limiter filter but as intended we cannot declare multiple rate limiters in configuration. We also tried using following:

```
    spring.cloud.gateway:
        routes:
        - id: 1
            uri: https://example.org/
        predicates:
        - Path=/path
        filters:
        - name: RequestRateLimiter
            args:
                redis-rate-limiter.replenishRate: 10
                redis-rate-limiter.burstCapacity: 20
                key-resolver: "#{@userKeyResolver}"
        - name: RequestRateLimiter
            args:
                redis-rate-limiter.replenishRate: 100
                redis-rate-limiter.burstCapacity: 200
                key-resolver: "#{@poolKeyResolver}"
```

In above description, pool can have multiple users within it. So user should be rate limited to replenish rate 10 requests per second whereas overall pool should be rate limited to replenish rate of 100 per second. But since same filter is being used, first config for rate limiter is overridden by second one.

We have looked at following post suggesting a way to rate limit based on a user plan independent of route: [Rate limiting based on user plan in Spring Cloud Gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50988095/rate-limiting-based-on-user-plan-in-spring-cloud-gateway)

However that does not apply to our use case since its rate limiting based on given API key independent of route. 
Is there a way we can achieve this using Spring cloud gateway. Any configuration that can allow us to support this use case.

Comment: did you find anything?

Comment: We can use predicates here.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit old, but you should be able to define multiple rate limiters. If you would have shared the error you are getting I could have taken a deeper look.
Anyway, running to a similar issue, I've added the @Primary annotation on the main key resolver (the poolKeyResolver) and it works like a charm. I have two keys saved with every API request received.